# Laravel Query Builder - Advanced Conditional Clauses (optional parameters)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need clauses with Query Builder that accept optional parameters. For example, consider the following:

We have three search fields for the product title, company name, and location (postal code, city or state). 2^3 (8) possibilities:

The location is with OR connected.

```
WHERE location.postal_code LIKE '%...%' OR location.city LIKE '%...%';
```

And the relationships between the search boxes

```
WHERE (location.postal_code LIKE '%...%' OR location.city LIKE '%...%') AND company.name LIKE '%...%';
```

We could write that with a raw query and if-else statements. How can we write that "clean" with the Query Builder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use where closure like this :

```
    $q->where(function($q) use($request) {
     if($request->code)
     {
       $q->orWhere('postal_code ','LIKE','%'.$request->code.'%');
     }

     if($request->city)
     {
       $q->orWhere('city','LIKE','%'.$request->code.'%');
     }

     if($request->companyName)
     {
      $q->where('companyName',.....);
     }
})->get();
```

So you have where, orWhere to form your query clean. Also you can pass your request to use it inside closure. Also you can use $q->orWhere to pass function inside it.